# How to root OnePlus 3 / OnePlus 3T / OnePlus 5 (A3000 / A3010 / A5000)?

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, twrp, oneplus-3, oneplus-5

The questions are simple:

**How can I root my OnePlus 3?**
**How can I root my OnePlus 3T?**
**How can I root my OnePlus 5?**

---

- Device: OnePlus 3 A3000
- Device: OnePlus 3T A3010
- Device: OnePlus 5 A5000
- Android Version: Stock 6.0 / Stock 7.0 / Stock 7.1
- Status: Out-of-the-box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)

Comment: @jerrett7 Nope, the question you link to is an *index* of all the rooting questions for each phone.

Comment: @DanHulme Ah, my bad. I had simply assumed this was a duplicate. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Disclaimer**: By attempting ant of the processes listed below, you accept full responsibility for your actions. I will not be held responsible if your device stops working, catches fire, or turns into a hipster and claims to have been modified before it is cool. Make sure you read the whole article and fully understand it **BEFORE** attempting it.

If you are experienced in unlocking & flashing recovery & rooting, here are the resources you need.

> Things you should download:
>
> TWRP Recovery for [OnePlus 3](https://twrp.me/oneplus/oneplusthree.html), [OnePlus 3T](https://twrp.me/oneplus/oneplusthree.html), [OnePlus 5](https://twrp.me/devices/oneplus5.html) (Choose the correct one for your model)
>   [SuperSU flashable ZIP](http://www.supersu.com/download) (Same across all phones)
>   [DM Verity and Forced Encryption Disabler](https://build.nethunter.com/android-tools/no-verity-opt-encrypt/) (Same across all phones)

Let's start from scratch.

### 1. Unlock Bootloader (Skip if unlocked already)

First make sure [you have installed `adb` and `fastboot`](/questions/42474) on your PC (or Mac). Ensure that your phone has at least 60% battery remaining, and that your PC is plugged in and won't shut down spontaneously during the process. The procedure doesn't take very long , but it‘s best to have enough charge in case something goes wrong.

**Backup (Optional)**: **Unlocking the bootloader will completely wipe all data from the device.** This includes apps, settings and even the contents of the internal sdcard (pictures, music, etc.). Copy all important files off the phone onto a PC or upload them to a cloud.

**USB Debugging**: On your phone go to **Settings > About phone** > Tap on Build number **7 times**. This will enable Developer options. Now go back to **Settings > Developer options > Enable USB debugging**

**Enable OEM Unlocking**: On your phone go to **Settings > Developer options**. Then enable the **OEM Unlocking** option. Also,a free advice, make sure that from now on, OEM unlocking option is enabled before you reboot. Because sometimes it might get disabled itself. <sub>Yeah that's weird so be careful.</sub>

**Enable Advanced Reboot**: On your phone go to **Settings > Developer options**. Then enable the **Advanced Reboot** option.

Turn the phone off. Then boot it into fastboot mode by holding volume up + power or select reboot to bootloader if advanced reboot is activated via developer options. The phone will display "fastboot" text indicating that it has successfully entered fastboot mode.

> **Warning: By proceeding this step, you will lose ALL data on your phone, including apps, games, musics, photos and everything else! Make proper backup before proceeding. Your warranty may also void, depending on your local law restriction and EULA.**

Plug the phone into your PC, then open a command prompt (or a terminal on Mac/Linux) and run

```
fastboot oem unlock
```

You would be greeted with a Unlock Bootloader Warning page, Hit the Vol button to select Yes and turn it Blue and Hit the Power Button to Execute the selection

Your device will reboot, showing you a Secure Boot Warning. Reboot into stock recovery and wipe all data. Once done, your phone will reboot into the OS. Continue to the next step to install Custom Recovery.

### 2. Install TWRP

Download TWRP (`.img`) and SuperSU (`.zip`) from the top of this article if you haven't had them yet. Place them on the phone internal memory or a USB stick as per convenience.

Enable **USB debugging**, **OEM Unlocking** and **Advanced Reboot** again as instructed in Section 1.

Reboot to fastboot mode again. Grab the command prompt and enter (replace `your-recovery.img` with the actual file name of the image you downloaded)

```
fastboot flash recovery your-recovery.img
```

Hit enter and wait for completion, then boot into recovery. **Do not use `fastboot reboot` because it will boot into OS instead of recovery. Use volume keys instead.**

### 3. Rooting

You will reach the screen asking you if you want to allow system modifications.
By swiping right, you will trigger DM-Verity, and if you don't follow the next step you will be unable to boot!

If you are going to root your device and follow the rest of these steps, then it's safe to swipe right and enable modifications.

Select your preferred language, tap “Never show this screen on boot again,” and swipe to allow modification.

<sup>PS: Flash DM Verity and format data only if you want to stay unencrypted, else you may just skip and continue with flashing SuperSU.</sup>

Without leaving TWRP, transfer the `no-verity-opt-encrypt` zip to your device over MTP and flash it or select it from internal as placed before, or use a USB stick (via OTG) and flash it (This will also allow you to use **Format Data** to completely disable your encryption if desired).

Go to “Wipe” section and tap “Format Data”, and type “yes” (If you want to mount internal storage).

Navigate to **Install ZIP** and select the SuperSU zip file to root OnePlus 5.

Swipe to install SuperSU and reboot your device.

<del>Bueno!</del> Congratulations! Your OnePlus 5 now has an unlocked bootloader, has a custom recovery installed and is rooted. Enjoy!!

---

Credits: This post is mostly copied from the original post on [XDA Developers Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-5/). I changed a few details so that it fits better on Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Thanks to the original author ([*Funk Wizard* on XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=6143932))!

**Original post**: [OnePlus 5: Unlock Bootloader | Flash TWRP | Root | Nandroid & EFS Backup & More !!](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-5/how-to/oneplus-5-unlock-bootloader-flash-twrp-t3624877)

Comment: after doing this will i still be able to enable and use OS phone encryption (settings > security & lock screen > encrypt phone)? is there a better way to encrypt the device? from your answer it would seem that the OS after root will be the same OxygenOS from oem. is that correct? if not is it possible to keep OxygenOS after root and OTA updates? i ask because i had cyanogen on a previous phone and did not like it, but do like oxygenos quite a bit.

Comment: @brnnnrsmssn Rooting does not change your OS. And of course, you can still opt-in to use `/data` encryption, which won't make anything wrong afterwards. If you update the OS via OTA, you must flash the SuperSU ZIP every time you update (but not the other steps like unlocking bootloader - those only needs to be done once).

Comment: so SuperSU manages root access for installed apps. unlocking the bootloader allows install of of custom images through twrp and the image is what is allowing root? did i get that all correct?

Comment: @brnnnrsmssn Unlocking bootloader allows you to flash a 3rd-party recovery like TWRP, and it's TWRP that allows you to flash custom images. Other than that, you got it all right.